# Custom Expire a document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest, mongoose

I want to expire documents in mongodb I found out that documents can expire and get deleted from the db if they have something like this in their schema:

```
{
name: string,
createdAt:{ type: Date,           
            expires: '1d', 
            default: Date.now() 
}
}
```

1d means all docs will expire in one day,
I want documents to have different expiry periods,
How can I get this value from the POST request body, if my body is

```
{ 'name': 'pius', 'expiry': '3d'}
```

And having my schema changed to

```
{
name: string,
createdAt:{ type: Date,           
            expires: string, 
            default: Date.now() 
}
}
```

Can I pass the expires string value via a request if yes how can it be done

Answer (score 0):

TTL indexes are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time. Data expiration is useful for certain types of information like machine generated event data, logs, and session information that only need to persist in a database for a finite amount of time.

```
db.eventlog.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

You can check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) link for more details.

Comment: I'm using express I want the user to be able specify the expireAfterSeconds value in the post request body so that documents have different expiry for different users other than that 3600 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework or the native nodejs http module. Parse the request and get the body of it transformed (or transforming) in JSON. Access de property and call the insert operation of the mongodb. In that case, the document will expire in the date specified on the request.

See express [req.body](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body) documentation and [router declaration](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) to get more details.